# how can i make query in angular with firebase firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i'm trying to make queries in angular 6 with firebase firestore, i have this code, already i downloaded the packege "npm firebase @angularfire" but doesn't work:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 
    '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import {Lesson} from './models/lesson.model'
    import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
    import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'; 
    import * as moment from 'moment';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      lessonRef:AngularFirestoreCollection<Lesson>;
      lesson$: Observable<Lesson[]>;
      endDate$: BehaviorSubject<Date>;

      constructor(afs:AngularFirestore){
        this.endDate$ = new BehaviorSubject(new Date('2017-12-24'));

        this.lesson$= this.endDate$.pipe(
          switchMap(date=>
          afs.collection<Lesson>('Lesson', ref => 
          ref.where('endDate', "==", date))
          .valueChanges(),
          ),
        );

      }
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you shared?

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining `ref` anywhere. As the [AngularFire documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#creating-a-query-with-primitivescalar-values) says:

> Queries are created by building on the [`firebase.firestore.CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference).

You'll need to define a `CollectionReference` as shown in the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
let ref = firebase.firestore().collection("Lessons");
```

Then you can define a AngularFire2 collection with a query on top of that with the code you have already.

Comment: but where do i must type it?

Comment: Before where you first use `ref`, so e.g. on a separate line right before `        this.lesson$= this.endDate$.pipe(`